# Self Relationship for a Node Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to establish a relationship between two properties of the same node.

I use this query to create `People` nodes:

```
//Animal
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///People.csv " AS row
FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (people:People{Name:row.PERSON_NAME, Parent_Name:row.PARENT_NAME, Age:row.PERSON_AGE)

RETURN people;
```

How do I create a self-relationship between `Name:row.PERSON_NAME` and `Parent_Name:row.PARENT_NAME` in order to have something like this:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why do you need a self-relationship? Are you actually trying to create a relationship between a child and its parent?

Comment: Yes I am, but I would like to create it without create two different node (e.g. child node, parent node)

Comment: Why? It seems totally unneeded. Since the 2 properties are already there in the same node, you don't need to follow a relationship. I would instead recommend that you put every person in his or her own node, with relationships between the nodes, which should be simpler if you could have multiple generations of the same family.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is not sensible.

1. You don't need to create a `PARENT` self-relationship when you know that a node always contains data for the parent. Just write your queries with that knowledge in mind.
2. Also, how would your data model handle a person with 2 or more parents?
3. And how would your model represent entire family trees?

A better data model would be one where every `Person` node contained just the data for a single person, with `PARENT` relationships between appropriate nodes.

For example (if you used a more sensible data model):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///People.csv " AS row FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
MERGE (p1:Person {name: row.PERSON_NAME})
ON CREATE SET p1.age = row.PERSON_AGE
MERGE (p2:Person {name: row.PARENT_NAME})
MERGE(p1)-[:PARENT]->(p2)
```